# Error in processing request Error code: 500 Error text: Internal Server Error on selecting any database in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i got this problem yesterday. I double-click on a database on the page *http://localhost/phpmyadmin/server_databases.php?db=&token=4f405e7340c0fe1b85b6e52f93520ebb* i keep on getting the error **'Error in processing request Error code: 500 Error text: Internal Server Error'** Any idea how i can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Am using ubuntu 16.04 phpmyadmin-version 4.5.4.1 mysql 5.7.17 php 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround**

Download and replace files for [Linux](https://kb.plesk.com/Attachments/kcs-69780/for_Linux.tar.gz) and for [Windows](https://kb.plesk.com/Attachments/kcs-69780/for_Windows.zip) .

**For Linux**

PRODUCT_ROOT_D/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php

PRODUCT_ROOT_D/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc ,where PRODUCT_ROOT_D is /usr/local/psa/ for RHEL-based systems, and /opt/psa/ for Debian-based systems.

**For Windows**

%plesk_dir%\admin\htdocs\domains\databases\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php

%plesk_dir%\admin\htdocs\domains\databases\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc

Comment: Thanks, for some reason this really helped

Answer (score 0):

put the url http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ remove rest of the path and query string

It should take you to the login page

Try loging in again

This is because the phpmyadmin is not able to authorize the token passed

Comment: I tried but for some reason my left-panel is not displaying so i have to use the databases tab which brings up the token

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php

```
function PMA_isRememberSortingOrder($analyzed_sql_results)
{
return $GLOBALS['cfg']['RememberSorting']
    && ! ($analyzed_sql_results['is_count']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_export']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_func']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_analyse'])
    && $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']
    && ((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
        || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
            && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))
    && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
}
```